# Why I am getting net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) in my django project?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have downloaded a template from online which has these files-

1. index.html
2. gallery.html
3. generic.html

I tried to connect these files into my django project.my django settings.py is:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '6+!*vrjoh*c56kf4u#1+7q=!t&yr6jbakf*8!d^)g-rgvj3w-_'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'projectapp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'projectapp.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets')
```

I included those static files in 'static' folder.I did run `python manage.py collectstatic`

and the first template is:

```
{%load static%}
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
    Snapshot by TEMPLATED
    templated.co @templatedco
    Released for free under the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 license (templated.co/license)
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Snapshot by TEMPLATED</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static 'assets/css/main.css' %}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page-wrap">

            <!-- Nav -->
                <nav id="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/index/" class="active"><span class="icon fa-home"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="/gallery/"><span class="icon fa-camera-retro"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="/generic/"><span class="icon fa-file-text-o"></span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

            <!-- Main -->
                <section id="main">

                    <!-- Banner -->
                        <section id="banner">
                            <div class="inner">
                                <h1>Hey, I'm Snapshot</h1>
                                <p>A fully responsive gallery template by <a href="https://templated.co">TEMPLATED</a></p>
                                <ul class="actions">
                                    <li><a href="#galleries" class="button alt scrolly big">Continue</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </section>

                    <!-- Gallery -->
                        <section id="galleries">

                            <!-- Photo Galleries -->
                                <div class="gallery">
                                    <header class="special">
                                        <h2>What's New</h2>
                                    </header>
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <div class="media">
                                            <a href="images/fulls/01.jpg"><img src="{%static 'images/thumbs/01.jpg'%}" alt="" title="This right here is a caption." /></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="media">
                                            <a href="images/fulls/05.jpg"><img src="{%static 'images/thumbs/05.jpg'%}" alt="" title="This right here is a caption." /></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="media">
                                            <a href="images/fulls/09.jpg"><img src="{%static 'images/thumbs/09.jpg'%}" alt="" title="This right here is a caption." /></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="media">
                                            <a href="images/fulls/02.jpg"><img src="{%static 'images/thumbs/02.jpg'%}" alt="" title="This right here is a caption." /></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="media">
                                            <a href="images/fulls/06.jpg"><img src="{%static 'images/thumbs/06.jpg'%}" alt="" title="This right here is a caption." /></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="media">
                                            <a href="images/fulls/10.jpg"><img src="{%static 'images/thumbs/10.jpg'%}" alt="" title="This right here is a caption." /></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="media">
                                            <a href="images/fulls/03.jpg"><img src="{%static 'images/thumbs/03.jpg'%}" alt="" title="This right here is a caption." /></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="media">
                                            <a href="images/fulls/07.jpg"><img src="{%static 'images/thumbs/07.jpg'%}" alt="" title="This right here is a caption." /></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <footer>
                                        <a href="/gallery/" class="button big">Full Gallery</a>
                                    </footer>
                                </div>
                        </section>

                    <!-- Contact -->
                        <section id="contact">
                            <!-- Social -->
                                <div class="social column">
                                    <h3>About Me</h3>
                                    <p>Mus sed interdum nunc dictum rutrum scelerisque erat a parturient condimentum potenti dapibus vestibulum condimentum per tristique porta. Torquent a ut consectetur a vel ullamcorper a commodo a mattis ipsum class quam sed eros vestibulum quisque a eu nulla scelerisque a elementum vestibulum.</p>
                                    <p>Aliquet dolor ultricies sem rhoncus dolor ullamcorper pharetra dis condimentum ullamcorper rutrum vehicula id nisi vel aptent orci litora hendrerit penatibus erat ad sit. In a semper velit eleifend a viverra adipiscing a phasellus urna praesent parturient integer ultrices montes parturient suscipit posuere quis aenean. Parturient euismod ultricies commodo arcu elementum suspendisse id dictumst at ut vestibulum conubia quisque a himenaeos dictum proin dis purus integer mollis parturient eros scelerisque dis libero parturient magnis.</p>
                                    <h3>Follow Me</h3>
                                    <ul class="icons">
                                        <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-facebook"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-instagram"><span class="label">Instagram</span></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>

                            <!-- Form -->
                                <div class="column">
                                    <h3>Get in Touch</h3>
                                    <form action="#" method="post">
                                        <div class="field half first">
                                            <label for="name">Name</label>
                                            <input name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="field half">
                                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                                            <input name="email" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="field">
                                            <label for="message">Message</label>
                                            <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="6" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                        <ul class="actions">
                                            <li><input value="Send Message" class="button" type="submit"></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </form>
                                </div>

                        </section>

                    <!-- Footer -->
                        <footer id="footer">
                            <div class="copyright">
                                &copy; Untitled Design: <a href="https://templated.co/">TEMPLATED</a>. Images: <a href="https://unsplash.com/">Unsplash</a>.
                            </div>
                        </footer>
                </section>
        </div>

        <!-- Scripts -->
            <script src="{ %static 'assets/js/jquery.min.js'%}"></script>
            <script src="{ %static 'assets/js/jquery.poptrox.min.js'%}"></script>
            <script src="{ %static 'assets/js/jquery.scrolly.min.js'%}"></script>
            <script src="{ %static 'assets/js/skel.min.js'%}"></script>
            <script src="{ %static 'assets/js/util.js'%}"></script>
            <script src="{ %static 'assets/js/main.js'%}"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I have succeded to connect the css files with the static.But in console i am getting this error:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/%7B%20%static%20'assets/js/jquery.min.js'%%7D net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
127.0.0.1/:131 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/%7B%20%static%20'assets/js/jquery.poptrox.min.js'%%7D net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
127.0.0.1/:132 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/%7B%20%static%20'assets/js/jquery.scrolly.min.js'%%7D net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
127.0.0.1/:133 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/%7B%20%static%20'assets/js/skel.min.js'%%7D net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
127.0.0.1/:134 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/%7B%20%static%20'assets/js/util.js'%%7D net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
127.0.0.1/:135 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/%7B%20%static%20'assets/js/main.js'%%7D net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

As a beginner,i tried some ways.But I dont know how to resolve this problem.Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

try this

the way to add the static URL is not correct.

```
<script src="{ %static 'assets/js/jquery.min.js'%}"></script>  # error
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
```

Refer this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files

Comment: well this time i got this error::---jquery.min.js'%20%%7D:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
how to solve this one?

Comment: @jubayerisfar please check the syntax again

Comment: .thanks a lot ! though i dont know how to format that.do you think this happened because i downloaded the file from online and so its formatted in that way from before?